# Collect Column names in Spark without using case when

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with follwing columns(A, A_1, B, B_1, C, C_1, D, D_1, E, E_1).
For example if A = A_1 and B <> B_1 and C <> C_1 and D <> D_1 and E <> E_1 then I want to create a column and mark it as 'B,C,D,E' for this records. Similarly all other combinations are possible

I tried writing case when but there are a lot of combinations

Comment: Did you try creating case statement by looping over column names?

Answer (score 1):

i'm unsure if it'd be possible without looping over columns. so, here's an easy approach that loops over your columns and checks if the column pair is not equal - if not equal, then output the column name. we can then concatenate the column names that we get from the loop.

example below

```py
data_ls = [
    (1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6),
    (1, 0, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6)
]

data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls). \
    toDF(['a', 'a_1', 'b', 'b_1', 'c', 'c_1', 'd', 'd_1'])

# +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
# |  a|a_1|  b|b_1|  c|c_1|  d|d_1|
# +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
# |  1|  1|  1|  3|  4|  4|  5|  6|
# |  1|  0|  1|  3|  4|  4|  5|  6|
# +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

# create condition statements for each column pair in a list
col_conditions = [func.when(func.col(k) != func.col(k+'_1'), func.lit(k)) for k in data_sdf.columns if not k.endswith('_1')]
# [Column<'CASE WHEN (NOT (a = a_1)) THEN a END'>,
#  Column<'CASE WHEN (NOT (b = b_1)) THEN b END'>,
#  Column<'CASE WHEN (NOT (c = c_1)) THEN c END'>,
#  Column<'CASE WHEN (NOT (d = d_1)) THEN d END'>]

# concatenate the case when statements with concat_ws
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('ineq_cols', func.concat_ws(',', *col_conditions)). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---------+
# |a  |a_1|b  |b_1|c  |c_1|d  |d_1|ineq_cols|
# +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---------+
# |1  |1  |1  |3  |4  |4  |5  |6  |b,d      |
# |1  |0  |1  |3  |4  |4  |5  |6  |a,b,d    |
# +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---------+
```

Comment: What if I have one  column F but dont have F_1, it will not work

Comment: @AdarshRajput - please share the details exactly how it would look like in your real world exercise and an expected output along with that. that will have a better reach. Re: your comment, you can manually provide the column names instead of the `data_sdf.columns`.